# importing css using require and webpack uses project root for font-face urls

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

We have 2 checked out projects which are **identical**. One imports the bootstrap & its glyphicons succesfully, the other gives a **404 on the glyphicons-halflings**.
 How ever when we **moved the font directory from node_modules/bootstrap/dist to the project root it succesfully included the font with the project.**
It seems like when webpack parses trough the required css files, it finds them, does what it does to include them, but the font-face urls it finds inside the required css, is mapped and looked-up for from the project root (this is why when we copied the fonts folder to the roots it was solved).

We are importing the bootstrap css in the **app.module.ts** files as following:

```
require('../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

anybody knows why it looks for included font-face urls from the root of the project and not relative to the css file the font-face is included in?

**DOES NOT WORK**

```
root
|_____app
|       |_app.module -> import('../node_modules.../bootstrap.css')
|_____node_modules
        |_bootstrap
          |_dist
          |  |_css
          |    |_bootstrap.css
          |_fonts
             |_glyphicons-halflings.otf
```

**WORKS**

```
root
|_____app
|       |_app.module -> import('../node_modules.../bootstrap.css')
|
|_____node_modules
|        |_bootstrap
|          |_dist
|            |_css
|              |_bootstrap.css
|_fonts      
   |_glyphicons-halflings.otf
```

Answer (score 0):

config:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.css', '.scss']
}
```

css file:

```
@import '~bootstrap/bootstrap.css';
```

What happens in the config file is that you are saying to webpack to look for all these extensions.

In the css file, this `~` is how webpack will know that this should be resolved.

Comment: the empty string in the extensions array threw a webpack error on not being competible with the API. 
Otherwise did exactly what was written, the @import did not import the bootstrap css, even though the path is right (in webstorm ctrl+click on path leads to correct file)